# Getting error while building ConnectyCube javascript demo app

Tags: javascript, nativescript, connectycube

I am developing a dating app in NativeScript angular. I want to add connectycube messaging plugin in my project. I got a demo app which is in JavaScript from GitHub repository. When I try to run it, it throws an error :

> ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-connectycube/lib/videocalling_conference/cubeConferenceClient.js 12:21
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:21)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

> DEVICE_INPUT_TYPES = DEVICE_INPUT_TYPES
> CALL_TYPES = CALL_TYPES

> @ ../node_modules/nativescript-connectycube/lib/cubeMain.js 49:31-88
> @ ./services/connectycube-service.js
> @ ./app.js
> @ multi @babel/polyfill ./app.js

If I just add this plugin in my project and build, it always throws the same error. How do I solve it?

Comment: do you use TypeScript or JS?

Answer (score 1):

You should add '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'